# How to Prevent Properties from Duplicating When using OpenApi and OneOf Several Objects

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator, smallrye

I have an interface that gets extended to a number of other interfaces and using OpenAPI 3.0.3 to annotate and generate to create our API contract.  The parent interface Schema lists the classes extending the interface as `oneOf` these other interfaces. The problem I'm having is that the properties in the interface are duplicated in the yaml file output: they're listed both in the parent interface and then again in the interfaces under their respective `oneOf` examples.  Is there a way to not have the interface properties displayed as their own, limiting them to only appear under the `oneOf` examples?  FWIW, we're using the SmallRye gradle plugin to handle the openApi generation stuff, but this problem existed before we implemented this.

**The Interface**

```
@Schema (description = "The Parent object",
    oneOf= {
        Mom.class,
        Dad.class,
        [...etc]
    })
public interface Parent {
    @Schema(description="The ID of the Parent", example=1)
    long parentId();

    @Schema(description="The name of the Parent", example="John")
    String parentName();
}
```

**Dad Interface**

```
@Schema (description = "The Dad object")
public interface Dad extends Parent {
    @Schema(description = "The age of the Dad", example=32)
    int age();

    @Schema(description="Dad's Favorite Toy", example="Cards")
    String favoriteToy();
}
```

**Mom Interface**

```
@Schema (description = "The Mom object")
public interface Mom extends Parent {
    @Schema(description = "Mom's Maiden Name", example="Jones")
    String maidenName();

    @Schema(description="Mom's Favorite Food", example="Pizza")
    String favoriteFood();
}
```

**Actual YAML**

```
    Parent:
      description: The Parent object
      type: object
      properties:
        parentId:
          description: The ID of the Parent
          example: 1
        promotionId:
          description: The name of the Parent
          example: John
      oneOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dad'
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Mom'
    Dad:
      description: The Parent object
      type: object
      properties:
        parentId:
          description: The ID of the Parent
          example: 1
        parentName:
          description: The name of the Parent
          example: John
        age:
          description: The age of the Dad
          example: 32
        favoriteToy: 
          description: Dad's Favorite Toy
          example: Cards
    Mom:
      description: The Mom object
      type: object
      properties:
        parentId:
          description: The ID of the Parent
          example: 1
        parentName:
          description: The name of the Parent
          example: John
        maidenName:
          description: Mom's Maiden Name
          example: Jones
        favoriteFood: 
          description: Mom's Favorite Food
          example: Pizza
```

**Desired YAML**

```
    Parent:
      description: The Parent object
      type: object
      oneOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dad'
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Mom'
        Dad:
      description: The Parent object
      type: object
      properties:
        parentId:
          description: The ID of the Parent
          example: 1
        parentName:
          description: The name of the Parent
          example: John
        age:
          description: The age of the Dad
          example: 32
        favoriteToy: 
          description: Dad's Favorite Toy
          example: Cards
    Mom:
      description: The Mom object
      type: object
      properties:
        parentId:
          description: The ID of the Parent
          example: 1
        parentName:
          description: The name of the Parent
          example: John
        maidenName:
          description: Mom's Maiden Name
          example: Jones
        favoriteFood: 
          description: Mom's Favorite Food
          example: Pizza
```

edited for a better example